# android - one package replaces another

Tags: android, eclipse

Android.
Eclipse.
Samsung S2
I have two apps I wrote.
Two different packages.
Both can be built and both run OK on the virtual and real device.
I want to leave both of them on the real device to play around with them for a couple of weeks.
Every time I install one, it replaces the other. Same happens whether I installing by running it from eclipse or by installing the APK straight on the phone.
The files have different names. The app names are different. I tried different package names. No luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the package name in your AndroidManifest.xml.
It's probably the same in both

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.check.package.name.here"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.00" >
```

Comment: You're right!When I change the package name in the manifest it won't compile - can't find the resource R (I think). Says "R cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: Changing the package name and saving it should have popped up a question that looks like: "The package definition in the manifest changed ... ". If it didn't try Project -> Clean

Comment: That did the trick (together with changing the import statement.